# How to concat file and a line on-fly?

Tags: bash, shell, cat, output

I would like to send to the stdout entire file + extra line. How to do this nicely? So far I did:

```
for LINE in $(cat $INPUT_FILE)
do
  echo $LINE
done
echo $EXTRA_LINE
```

How to do this bash way (for real)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
cat -- "$INPUT_FILE"
echo "$EXTRA_LINE"
```

Comment: I have probably fainted for a second, gee... Thank you!

Comment: I also was checking your code twice if I had missed something. :)